# Jgrowl message giving error in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, jgrowl

I am using `jgrowl.js` and `jgrowl.css` to display a jgrowl message.  In the console I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined in 268 line jgrowl.js file.

This is the line:

```
$(this).data("jGrowl").created = new Date();
```

Comment: Please give more information like a minimal code snipplet, browser you use and jgrowl.js version. This looks like a bug in jgrowl.js but difficult to tell with your question.

Comment: jGrowl 1.2.13 using chrome browser

Comment: Try the latest version, it should be 1.4.1.

Comment: More context is needed, specifically what is 'this' at the point of execution.